# How to change camera angle in highcharts 3d

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to implement highcharts 3d to my project, but can not figure out how to achieve the desired effect. I want all columns in my 3d chart to have the same angle and depth, the x-axis is vertical.

My problem is the camera always center at columns in the middle so the effect on far right columns is different from the far left ones.

This the chart is currently looks like:

[image]
What I want it to look like (taken from Microsoft Words):

[image]

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hchoang/rLnhfxc8/23/

This is the chart 3d config is currently look like:

```
   chart: {
     type: 'column',
     options3d: {
       enabled: true,
       alpha: 0,
       beta: 0,
       depth: 25,
       viewDistance: 25
     },
     margin: [undefined, 0, undefined, 0]
   },
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your current work with sample data in some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel: Thank you for your reply, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hchoang/rLnhfxc8/23/) is my current work with some example data.

Comment: @catcon I've been trying to do this exact thing with my 3d column chart, but whenever I add `beta` to angle all the columns in the same way, the columns get angled on the z-axis such that they are no longer equidistant from the bottom. Have you had any luck creating the chart effect from your MS Word screenshot?

Comment: @vich: I can't find the solution for highchart, the closed one you can find from the answer below. I ended up switch to [amchart](https://www.amcharts.com/). My project was new so I can afford to switch library.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't get it to work with highcharts so ended up settling for 0 `beta` and adding `alpha` and `depth`. Not exactly what I wanted, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good approach will be to use this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-column-interactive/) to find wanted **alpha**, **beta** and **depth** values and set them to your demo.

For me will be something smiliar to those values:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ctxk9hmb/

Code:

```
options3d: {
  enabled: true,
  alpha: 10,
  beta: 15,
  depth: 100,
  //viewDistance: 25
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.options3d